# Calculating Mean of Number of Files Results in "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables"

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm working on an assignment in Coursera where we are to read in a collection of CSV files and calculate the mean of a given varriable over that series of CSV files (given by the pollutant argument) An explanation of the assignment is located below. My code works until the 271st file after which I get the described error.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){
    path<-0
    total<-0
    quan<-0
    file<-0
    numberterms <-0

    for (value in id)
    {
      if(value<10)
      {
              prefix<-"00"
      }
      if(value>=10 && value<100)
      {
              prefix<-"0"
      }
      if(value>99)
      {
              prefix <-""
      }

    path[value]<- paste(directory,"/",prefix,as.character(value), ".csv", sep="")

    file<- read.csv(as.character(path[value]))
    total[value]<-sum(file[c(pollutant)], na.rm=TRUE)
    quan[value]<-sum(as.numeric(!is.na(file[c(pollutant)])), na.rm=TRUE)
    }       

     sum(total, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(quan, na.rm = TRUE)
     }
```

Text of Assignment:

> The zip file contains 332 comma-separated-value (CSV) files containing pollution monitoring >data for fine particulate matter (PM) air pollution at 332 locations in the United States. Each >file contains data from a single monitor and the ID number for each monitor is contained in the >file name. For example, data for monitor 200 is contained in the file "200.csv". Each file >contains three variables:
>
> > Date: the date of the observation in YYYY-MM-DD format (year-month-day)
> >     sulfate: the level of sulfate PM in the air on that date (measured in micrograms per cubic meter)
> >     nitrate: the level of nitrate PM in the air on that date (measured in micrograms per cubic meter)
> >     For this programming assignment you will need to unzip this file and create the directory >'specdata'. Once you have unzipped the zip file, do not make any modifications to the files in >the 'specdata' directory. In each file you'll notice that there are many days where either >sulfate or nitrate (or both) are missing (coded as NA). This is common with air pollution >monitoring data in the United States.
>
> Part 1
>
> Write a function named 'pollutantmean' that calculates the mean of a pollutant (sulfate or >nitrate) across a specified list of monitors. The function 'pollutantmean' takes three >arguments: 'directory', 'pollutant', and 'id'. Given a vector monitor ID numbers, >'pollutantmean' reads that monitors' particulate matter data from the directory specified in >the 'directory' argument and returns the mean of the pollutant across all of the monitors, >ignoring any missing values coded as NA. A prototype of the function is as follows

Comment: As of today there are 157 hits to an SO search for "pollutantmean". Have you done an searching prior to posting this homework assignment?

Comment: Yes, I did a lot of searching and developed the function myself. I think I went about the process differently than most people so my function looks quite different.